# synchronize/pipe jquery(ajax>success) with user defined function(s)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-deferred

problem:

1. Fx-1: getdB-Record() from any required dB-table
2. Fx-2: populateTable() with Fx-1 Data WITHOUT any formatting
3. Fx-3: formatTable() later format table. **And here is the problem**.. this fx runs before population of Table
4. getting sequence: Fx-1, Fx-3, Fx-2
5. required sequence: Fx-1, Fx-2, Fx-3

plz help me out :) thanks. i tried several-codes and learn (deferred obj, queue, pipe, when, then, done) but it seems im missing something.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
$.when(
    //(fx-1)getDB-Records()
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        success: function(data) {
            //call (fx-2) just populate table without formating
            populateTable(data);
        }
    })
).then( function(){
    //(fx-3) formatTable()
    console.log('Problem: Format table starts before population of Table');
 });

});
function populateTable(data){
    //(fx-2) just populate table without formating
    //takes a little time
    setTimeout(function (){console.log('populate Table'); }, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several points :

- "Fx" to mean "function" will confuse the marrow out of people. "fn" is the conventional abbreviation.
- There's no need to wrap `$.ajax()` in `$.when()`. `$.ajax()` returns an inherently promise-compatible object with chainable `.done()`, `.fail()`, `.always()` and `.then()` methods.
- When `$.ajax()` became promise-compatible, use of the `success:` callback (in the options map) became unnecessary. It remains only for backward compatibility and may one day be removed. Mixing the old approach with the new is not recommended.
- the function wrapper around the simple `populateTable()` call is not necessary. You can specify `populateTable` by name.
- `populateTable()` must return a Promise (to a chained `.then()`) in order for something to happen after its asynchronous activity has completed.

You probably want something like this :

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    //(fn-1)getDB-Records()
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/'
    }).then(populateTable).done(function(txt) {
        //(fn-3) formatTable()
        console.log('populateTable reports: ' + txt);
    });
});

function populateTable(data) {
    //(fn-2) just populate table without formatting
    var dfrd = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function () {
        var message = 'Table populated';
        console.log('populateTable says: ' + message);
        dfrd.resolve(message);
    }, 1);
    return dfrd.promise();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Mr. Beetroot. It help and answers few more questions in my mind. i hv just started learning jquery 3-days back. I found and self-answer my posted but this one is more appropriate and suits my needs.

Comment: with due respect :)
for @ "Fx"-confuse the marrow out of people
Fx,Bx,Rx were only meant for reference

Fx- used by Microsoft-Excel still in 2013 as symbol for Inserting Functions and Microsoft Office is in marrow of billons of users.. however, from next time i will use 'fn'.

i learn from you and i respect you for that. may God bless you always.

Comment: Blue Sky, what I didn't say was that "fx" has a particular meaning in jQuery, where it is the default animation queue. When spoken in English, "fx" sounds like "effects". You are doing very well after just 3 days. God bless.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my query but still open for any good solution/suggestion :)

```
//Entry point
   populate($("#mytable"), fmtTblFilter);
--- or ---
   populate($("mySelectBox"), $.noop());

function getdB(elem){
    return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    });
}

function populate(elem, callback){
    var dBRet;

    dBRet = getdB(elem);
    dBRet.success(function(data) {

         switch (elem.get(0).tagName) {
           case 'SELECT':
               populateSelect(elem, data);
               break;

           case 'TABLE':
               populateTable(elem, data).pipe(callback);
               break;

           default:
               break;
         }
    });
}

function populateTable(elem, data){
    var d = $.Deferred();

    //code here

    d.resolve();
    return d.promise();  
}

function fmtTblFilter(){
    var d = $.Deferred();

    //code here

    d.resolve();
    return d.promise();
}

function populateSelect(elem, data){
    //code here
}
```